# Custom list update function not working

Tags: custom-list

What will be the URL for updating the custom list (customer)  row with one of the columns as a reference?

For example, there are few columns in the list with `name, age, gender, email, phone no`, I want to update all the row details with customer `name` as the reference.

I am using the below URL input method but not succeeded

```
 url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl +"/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('CustomerList')/items?$filter=(Name eq 'selected.Name')",
```

Please suggest me the exact method and url to update row details